# Karma - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: xxxCtrl - Code works in Browser though

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am new to AngularJS, and while I can get the basic tutorial steps to work, I am trying to expand my structure for the real application that will be developed.  Modules will be added into this application on going.

Directory Structure:

/WebSite/app

/Website/app/lib

/Website/app/Modules/App.js

/Website/app/Modules/Events/controllers

/Website/app/Modules/Events/views

/Website/app/Modules/Events/test_user

UpcomingEventsSpec.js

/Website/app/Modules/Events/test_end2end

Index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Modules/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="UpcomingEventsCtrl">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="EventData in Events">
        {{EventData.Name}}
        <p>{{EventData.Date}}</p>
        <p>{{EventData.Location}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Modules\app.js  - This will move to Modules\Events\UpcomingEvents.js in the future when loading from RESTful service

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('UpcomingEventsCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.Events = [
    {
        'Date': 20140329,
        'Time': 100000,
        'Name': 'Event 1',
        'Location': 'Location 1',
    },
    {
        'Date': 20140208,
        'Time': 093000,
        'Name': 'Event 2',
        'Location': 'Location 2',
    }];
});
```

Modules\Events\test_unit\UpcomingEventsSpec.js

```
describe('App Controllers', function() 
{
    beforeEach(module('App'));

    describe('UpcomingEventsCtrl', function()
    {
        it('Should create "Upcoming Events" with 2 entries', function()
        {
            var scope = {},
                Control = new UpcomingEventsCtrl(scope);
            expect(scope.Events.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```

Karma Output

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) App Controllers UpcomingEventsCtrl Should create
"Upcoming Events" with 2 entries FAILED
        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: UpcomingEventsCtrl
            at A:/app/Modules/Events/test_unit/UpcomingEvents_Spec.js:10
            at A:node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:117
            at A:node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
            at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:189
            at http://localhost:9876/context.html:59
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.002 secs / 0.002 secs)
```

From Karma:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
    'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
    'app/Modules/*.js',
    'app/Modules/Events/**/*.js',
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude : [
    'app/lib/angular/angular-loader.js',
    'app/lib/angular/*.min.js',
    'app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'
],
```

The data appears on the website when running, but I cannot run the tests without errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how you instantiate the controller in your test. You are doing:

```
Control = new UpcomingEventsCtrl(scope);
```

But no where have you defined a Javascript classed called `UpcomingEventsCtrl`. You're defining this controller in the Angular app correctly, and you just need to create the controller correctly in your test.

You can do that by adding another `beforeEach()` function to your test:

```
describe('App Controllers', function() 
{
    // these will be initialized in the beforeEach()
    var controller, scope;

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope;
      controller = $controller('UpcomingEventsCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    describe('UpcomingEventsCtrl', function()
    {
        it('Should create "Upcoming Events" with 2 entries', function()
        {
            // for the purpose of this example, confirm the controller is
            // not undefined/null
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
            expect(controller).not.toBeNull();
            expect(scope.Events.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```